# How do I declare a Multi-set that contains arrays of a certain size?

Tags: c++, arrays, set, multiset

I'm relatively new to C++. I'm trying to declare a multiset that contains arrays of size 2. I've tried the following but I don't think it does what I want it to do:

```
multiset<int> nameOfSet[2];
```

Can someone please tell me what this line does? If this is wrong, please explain to me why and tell me how to do it correctly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The line is declareing a 2-element array of `multiset<int>`. You may want `multiset<std::array<int, 2> > nameOfSet;`.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> multiset<int> nameOfSet[2];
> ```
>
> Can someone please tell me what this line does?

It declares a variable that is an array of two multisets of int.

> How do I declare a Multi-set that contains arrays of a certain size?

You cannot. Arrays cannot be elements of any standard container.

However, arrays can be members of classes, and classes can be elements of containers. There is a standard template for such array wrapper: `std::array`. So, you can do:

```
std::multiset<std::array<int, 2>> nameOfSet;
```